# unable to find a solution for the 'reading 'toString' error. - Type Script

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
type MetaData = {
  currentFBYear: number,
  dataWorksheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet,
  year1stDate: Date
}

type AbsenceRecord = {
  employeeNum: string | number,
  type: string,
  dateStr: string
}

function main(wb: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  console.log(`Starded getMetaDataBy`)
  const metaDataObj = getMetaDataBy(wb);
  console.log(`Finished getMetaDataBy`)
}


const getMetaDataBy = (wb: ExcelScript.Workbook): MetaData => {
  const currentFBYear = getCurrentFBYear();
  const ws = wb.getWorksheet(currentFBYear.toString()); // Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
  const year1stDate = ws.getRange('A1').getValue();

  const resultObj: MetaData = {
    currentFBYear,
    dataWorksheet: ws,
    year1stDate: new Date(`${currentFBYear}-04-01`)
  }
  return resultObj;
}


const getCurrentFBYear = (): number => {
  const today = new Date();
  const currentYear = today.getFullYear();

  const _0401 = new Date(`${currentYear}-04-01`);
  const _1231 = new Date(`${currentYear}-12-31`);
  if (today >= _0401 && today <= _1231)
    return (today >= _0401 && today <= _1231) ? currentYear : currentYear - 1;
}
```

When running this code, I encounter the error 'Line 82: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString'). I'm seeking advice or a solution to resolve this issue

I didn't address the part where toString is being called when employeeNum is undefined. I attempted to modify the code to safely handle calling toString when employeeNum is undefined, but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Your getCurrentFBYear function only returns `if (today >= _0401 && today <= _1231)` so it could be undefined

Comment: `getCurrentFBYear` doesn't handle the case when the condition `(today >= _0401 && today <= _1231)` doesn't pass.

Comment: constcurrent FBYear = getCurrentFBYear() || getCurrentFBYear() - 1;
const csvSheetName = `${currentFBYear}_csv`; 
The error still occurs even after making the code modification in the mentioned way. Are there any other issues that could be causing this?

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue when `getCurrentFBYear` returns `undefined`, it doesn't return a number when the `if` condition fails. You've to add an alternative return value when the current date is not within the given limits. It looks like you should remove the `if` and return the result of the ternary as it is.

Comment: Teemu, thank you so much for your advice! Have a joyful start to the new year!